# How do I branch on a past Revision in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch

I have a code base in Mercurial and I am using TortoiseHg 5.0.2. I am the only developer though I do rarely merge in some low level stuff from another developer. This should make my ask a bit easier. Since I am the only developer and I find branches in Hg a bit weird (somewhere between SVN and Git branches), I have been working off default.

I made a mistake a couple months ago and didn't branch when starting a new feature. Recently, a new requirement came in to deliver a build to a new customer with some specific changes but without the new feature. I identified the revision to branch from (2462) and I must have messed up the branch because it didn't branch the way I expected.

In order to make a build to start testing, (time was of the essence) I just created a new copy of the repository at revision 2462 and made some bug fixes and additions. The intent is to merge the two repositories after the delivery.

The repository main2 is the main line.

[image]

The repository main is the one I created for the customer.

[image]

I finally created branches for each effort.

What I would like to do is create a branch and move my main changes to the main2 repository but every time I try, Hg wants to merge some files and I don't want to pollute my Randy Install with anything from post 2462. So what I would like to end up with is:

[image]

I have read the branch section of the manual but it talks about branching from the tip. I also can't push my changes in main to the server without merging in the Rem2 branch stuff (understandably), which I don't want to do yet. So they only exist on my machine.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this or maybe something similar to make my future merge easier?

Comment: In main try `hg up 2463` then `hg pull /path/to/main2` then `hg merge tip` ? (Obviously make a backup of both repos beforehand.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminology - Mercurial has both named and anonymous branches. They function almost the same way in nearly all cases. There is no absolute right/wrong way to branch - either is workable. Putting new features into a named branch may certainly make sense but is not really going to change the overall workflow of how you merge things back together very much.

You don't have to start a new branch from `tip`. You can start a new branch from any existing changeset. For instance if you were to update to an older changeset and then make a new commit, you just branched (anonymously). You could also have used `hg branch` first and then committed, but the end result in terms of the topological view of history would basically be the same.

---

> I made a mistake a couple months ago and didn't branch when starting a
> new feature...
>
> I just created a new copy of the repository at revision 2462 and made
> some bug fixes and additions.

By creating a new copy of the repo, you effectively *did* create a branch. This is perfectly OK and actually can be a very useful technique since you can have parallel versions of the same codebase available at the same time.

This is not much different than if two developers each had their own local copy (clone) of the repo, or if you used multiple dev PCs, etc.

If you need to do this again in the future, its OK to just copy the entire repo via the filesystem. You could also re-clone from a server (`hg clone path\to\master\repo`) or clone from a local repo (`hg clone path\to\main\`). Aside from clone I often prefer to use [`hg share`](https://The%20intent%20is%20to%20merge%20the%20two%20repositories%20after%20the%20delivery.) which has a similar result but is faster and uses less disk space.

---

> The intent is to merge the two repositories after the delivery.

You don't really "merge" repositories, you merge branches. And to do that you first have to synchronize your repositories.

Let's assume you want `main` to be the final repo with all work in it. (Maybe `main2` will eventually get deleted). What you need to do is pull changes from `main2` into `main`, and then merge branches.

Something like this:

```
cd path\to\main\
hg pull path\to\main2\
```

At this point you will have something like your third diagram.

Since you want to leave the state of `Randy Install` branch alone, that means you need to merge FROM that branch INTO `default`.

```
hg up default
hg merge `Randy Install`
```

You may well have merge conflicts at this point. But that is just a fact of life, if the same files have been modified in both branches you'll have to reconcile the changes. THG and KDiff3 will do a good job in most cases of solving that automatically, but if not there's no way around doing it manually.

Finally, do an `hg commit` of the merge.

The end result will be that `default` is up to date.